# How do I get the sum of all values in a map with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, maps

**PROBLEM**

I have a map that looks like this:

```
const myMap= new Map();

myMap.set("MapItem1", [1, 4.5]);
myMap.set("MapItem2", [0, 3]);
myMap.set("MapItem3", [1, 10]);
myMap.set("MapItem4", [1, 1]);
```

As you can see, this map has 1 key, and an array with 2 values. What I'm trying to do is get the sum of all the second values.

**Solution Attempt**

I tried to write a function that looks like this:

```
 function sumArray(map[k,[v, v1]]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < map.length; i += 1) {
    sum += map[v1];
  }
  return sum;
  }
```

My thought is to use a function which takes a map object that matches the one above and iterate through it, summing the second value parameter as I go.

This simply hasn't worked for me, returning nothing at all. Would appreciate any help seeing flaws in my logic, or advice for different solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to loop over the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) of the map and then sum them up one by one.

```js
const myMap= new Map();

myMap.set("MapItem1", [1, 4.5]);
myMap.set("MapItem2", [0, 3]);
myMap.set("MapItem3", [1, 10]);
myMap.set("MapItem4", [1, 1]);

let sum = 0;
for(const arr of myMap.values()) {
  sum += arr[1];
}
console.log(sum);
```